# Is there a way to conditionally format data validated entries to change the values within the cells themselves?

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have an attendance sheet I'd like to edit that has data validation pertaining to credit applied towards the overall attendance percentage, with a 1 meaning the person was there, .5 for late, 0 for calling off appropriately, -0.5 for calling off late, and -1 for no call not showing. In attempting to equate these numbers to the words associated with them, I'm not seeing a way to either: **A)** Make this human-readable with the entry of a 0.5 inside of the box being changed to late, but also usable within attendance calculation, or **B)** be able to pseudo enumerate my list of words to associate them with numbers

I've attempted to use most of the data validation and conditional formatting options, but I'm unfamiliar with the custom code that could be run to make this a possibility.

This is a copy of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IXZqySfbED2TCX-yo1aScupdof1WZXhdQ820zlqiMn8/edit?usp=sharing
Under the Attendance tab

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D8hZ_k7xmb9ZHP1GwQJg5jLLM1sM0nXd9JSIvAWk2Lc/edit#gid=1113298056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B2** and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA((SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(C2:2), 
 'Data Validation'!C:D, 2, 0))/COUNTA(C2:2))*1)))
```

[image: 0]